# Freetts javax.speech.EngineException

Tags: java, javasound, apache-felix, freetts

I am using converting text to Speech to send to my SIP application. I keep getting this Error

```
javax.speech.EngineException: javax.speech.Central: no class found for com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral
    at javax.speech.Central.registerEngineCentral(Central.java:706)
    at Text2Speech.TextToSpeech.initEnglish(TextToSpeech.java:49)
    at gov.nist.jrtp.test.send_recv.jrtpTest.EncodeRTP(jrtpTest.java:192)
    at gov.nist.jrtp.test.send_recv.jrtpTest.<init>(jrtpTest.java:93)
    at org.universAAL.samples.sip.exporter.SIPExpImpl.<init>(SIPExpImpl.java:81)
    at org.universAAL.samples.sip.exporter.Activator.start(Activator.java:20)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:633)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1817)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1734)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1143)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have included all the required dependencies , I have spent wholw day unable to resolve this error.

When I try to run  my code as a normal java application it works fine.

Code:

```
 public void initEnglish(String voiceName) {

      System.out.println("Using voice: " + voiceName);

          try {
              if (desc == null) {

                  System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");

//                desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null,"general",    Locale.US,null,null);//new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.US);
                  desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.US);
                  Central.registerEngineCentral  ("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
//                Central.registerEngineCentral  ("com.sun.speech.engine.synthesis.text.TextEngineCentral");

                  synthesizer = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
                  synthesizer.allocate();
                  synthesizer.resume();
                  VoiceManager vm=VoiceManager.getInstance();
                  voice=vm.getVoice(voiceName);
                  if(voice!=null)
                    {
                    voice.allocate();
                    }

                  freetts=new FreeTTS(voice);
                  System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                  FileLocation =System.getProperty("user.dir");
                  audioPlayer = new SingleFileAudioPlayer(FileLocation+"/NewVoice", Type.WAVE);
                  voice.setAudioPlayer(audioPlayer);
                }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (EngineException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AudioException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (EngineStateError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
```

Comment: How are you running this test ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like your program can not find the sound library

Comment: I have different project bundles one of them is phone project while includes the sip, rtp ans freetts codes . I maven install each project individually and then run it together as OSGi Framework.

Comment: But I have included it and has the lowest level

Comment: Does any one know where I can find the complete source code for the java sound library. The one I downloaded from the website does not contain the EngineCentral and other libraries I require.

Comment: This spec on EngineCentral is from 1998! http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/javax/speech/EngineCentral.html Is this deprecated/unsupported code that you are working with?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but the other didn't get an answer either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090534/freetts-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-speech-enginecentral